# Particle size-energy distribution

Tags: applied-chemistry

I am not chemist, I am mathematician and interested in Population Balance Equations. I have a question about particle size-(breakage) energy distribution which mentioned in this article: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0032591011001458.

In this paper, author says (in top of section 3.2) he divide size and energy interval to 100 intervals. I divide size interval (0-6 mm) to 100 intervals but I don't know how can I divide energy interval. Is there anybody can help me?

Comment: I can't see the article as its behind a paywall, however, its basically done in the same way as you divided sizes. Somewhere there must be mention of maximum and minimum energies.

Comment: @porphyrin you can use website sci-hub.bz for free access to it. by the way, this is a related article which I used most of: http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/aic.14358/abstract